# How to show tooltip for text in SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg, tooltip

I need a tooltip when the user hovers over text in SVG. Also, the text and the tooltip content should be modifiable with javascript.

The following works in Firefox but not Chrome. What's the correct way to do this?

HTML:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100" height="100">
    <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:black;stroke-width:0"></rect>
    <text id="text1" x="50" y="15" text-anchor="end">text1</text>
    <text id="text2" x="80" y="15" text-anchor="end"
      transform="translate(0,50)">text2</text>
</svg>
```

Javascript (with jQuery):

```
$('#text1').attr('title', 'Tooltip 1');
$('#text2').attr('title', 'Tooltip 2');
```

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/getvictor/ctaVA/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A title child element will act as a tooltip.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100" height="100">
    <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:black;stroke-width:0"></rect>
    <text id="text1" x="50" y="15" text-anchor="end"><title>Tooltip 1</title>text1</text>
    <text id="text2" x="80" y="15" text-anchor="end"
      transform="translate(0,50)"><title>Tooltip 2</title>text2</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: With tooltip being part of the text body, how to modify the text while keeping the tooltip? Like: `$('#text1').text('newText');`

Comment: That will modify the tooltip text. I'm asking how to modify the text text without blowing away the tooltip.

Comment: $('#text1').contents().eq(1).wrap("<p />").parent().text('New').contents().unwrap();

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `<title>` element.

> Note that those implementations that do use `<title>` to display a tooltip often will only do so if the `<title>` is indeed the **first child element** of its parent.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title

So, in your example, that would be

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100" height="100">
   <title id="title1">This is a tooltip</title>
   <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:black;stroke-width:0"></rect>
   ...
```